# How to avoid overlapping dashed lines in Tikz-Uml associations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I'm using the Tikz-Uml package, and I keep getting overlapping dashed lines when multiple classes implement the same interface:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \umlclass[x=-4, y=0]{First}{}{
        \umlvirt{+execute(): bool}
    }

    \umlclass[x=-4, y=-4, type=abstract]{Second}{}{
        \umlvirt{+execute(): bool}
    }

    \umlclass[x=2, y=-4]{Third}{}{
        +execute(): bool \\
    }

    \umlclass[x=2, y=-6]{Fourth}{}{
        +execute(): bool \\
    }

    \umlclass[x=2, y=-8]{Fifth}{}{
        +execute(): bool \\
    }

    \umlimpl{Third}{Second}
    \umlHVHimpl[anchors=west and east]{Fourth}{Second}
    \umlHVHimpl[anchors=west and east]{Fifth}{Second}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results with:

[image]

How can I avoid overlapping dashed lines in associacions for the Fourth and the Fifth class?

Comment: This is a problem when using dependency, import and implements relations in tikz-uml. Personally, I did not find how to do it properly and when needed, I do it manually. Sure it is ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think that can be solved manually, playing with the position of UML elements. Maybe this is a ugly way but useful.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \umlclass[x=-4, y=0]{First}{}{
            \umlvirt{+execute(): bool}
        }
        \umlclass[x=-4, y=-4, type=abstract]{Second}{}{
            \umlvirt{+execute(): bool}
        }
        \umlclass[x=2, y=-4]{Third}{}{
            +execute(): bool \\
        }
        \umlclass[x=2, y=-6.1]{Fourth}{}{%previous y - 0.1
            +execute(): bool \\
        }
        \umlclass[x=2, y=-8.2]{Fifth}{}{%previous y - 0.2
            +execute(): bool \\
        }
        \umlimpl{Third}{Second}
        \umlHVHimpl[anchors=west and east]{Fourth}{Second}
        \umlHVHimpl[anchors=west and east]{Fifth}{Second}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Hi, didn't have time to try this until now. I still get an overlap at between Third and Second class...